# Auto configure Jupyter password from command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I learnt that Jupyter-notebook can be configured with a password instead of token.

Two steps-

```
$ jupyter notebook password
Enter password:  ****
Verify password: ****
[NotebookPasswordApp] Wrote hashed password to /Users/you/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json
```

I want to automate this process (in Dockerfile, I won't be able to enter manually when prompted for password), something like this,

```
echo 'password' | jupyter notebook password
```

This should auto input my `'password'` to the shell when prompted to *Enter password* and *Verify password*

Can you give me a shell command which can automate this password setup without user intervention.

Comment: Sending password over an `echo` is highly insecure. Is it ok to expose the password this way

Comment: Yeah. In this case, it is okay.

Comment: So didn't your attempt work? `echo 'password' | jupyter notebook password`? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Nope. When I run this command `jupyter notebook password` it prompts for password, and once entered it asks to verify it. I would like a shell script to automate password input to this command stdin.

Comment: Try `expect` utility

Answer (score 6):

### 1. Generate hash with [passwd](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/b8b66332e2023e83d2ee04f83d8814f567e01a4e/notebook/auth/security.py#L24) function

Generate hash for **your_password** manually in console:

```
In [1]: from notebook.auth import passwd; passwd()
Enter password: *************
Verify password: *************
Out[1]: 'sha1:a58051cdbd5c:8ee35109f0076445b37be17d926e56bee5910bea'
```

or in script:

```
$ python3 -c "from notebook.auth import passwd; print(passwd('your_password'))"
sha1:a58051cdbd5c:8ee35109f0076445b37be17d926e56bee5910bea
```

### 2. Run jupyter with NotebookApp.password [param](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html)

When started:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.password='sha1:a58051cdbd5c:8ee35109f0076445b37be17d926e56bee5910bea'
```

or via jupyter config, e.g. in Dockerfile as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49774783/7647325):

```
RUN jupyter notebook --generate-config
RUN echo "c.NotebookApp.password='sha1:a58051cdbd5c:8ee35109f0076445b37be17d926e56bee5910bea'">>/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Comment: Small note: in jupyter lab, the command is `python3 -c "from IPython.lib.security import passwd; print(passwd(passphrase='your_password', algorithm='sha1'))"`

Comment: In jupyter notebook the passwd function has moved to jupyter_server: `python3 -c "from jupyter_server.auth import passwd; print(passwd('your_password'))"`

Answer (score 5):

You can provide the token argument as a workaround for a password to jupyter in Docker:

`sudo docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 -v /home/YOUR_USER:/home/ -e USERID=1003 continuumio/anaconda3 /opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --NotebookApp.token='YOUR_PASSWORD' --allow-root --notebook-dir=/home/`

Then, enter in your address:8888 (without the token) and, when prompted, enter your token instead of your password.

Don't forget to check your USERID (with the `id` command in terminal), to ensure you will be able to read+write in sync with folders outside your container.

Comment: NotebookApp.token= just will force convert YOUR_PASSWORD to hex

Comment: You are right, that's why I mentioned this is a workaround

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this issue with [this commit](https://github.com/fablabbcn/DataVisPlanner/commit/d416661d978d66811b0d325a463be5fd410dfef3). I created [a custom python file](https://github.com/fablabbcn/DataVisPlanner/blob/master/jupyter/setup.py) that reuses part of the notebook passwd() function and then stores it in the *~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py* file. In my case I'm using a docker-compose so passing the password to be saved was a bit more complex, but you can pass it as an environment file easily with Docker:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import fileinput
import hashlib
import random
from ipython_genutils.py3compat import cast_bytes, str_to_bytes

# Get the password from the environment
password_environment_variable = os.environ.get('JUPYTER_PASSWORD')

# Hash the password, this is taken from https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/notebook/auth/security.py
salt_len = 12
algorithm = 'sha1'
h = hashlib.new(algorithm)
salt = ('%0' + str(salt_len) + 'x') % random.getrandbits(4 * salt_len)
h.update(cast_bytes(password_environment_variable, 'utf-8') + str_to_bytes(salt, 'ascii'))
password = ':'.join((algorithm, salt, h.hexdigest()))

# Store the password in the configuration
setup_line = "#c.NotebookApp.password = ''"
new_setup_line = setup_line.replace("''", "u'" + password + "'")
new_setup_line = new_setup_line.replace("#", "")
setup_file = os.getenv("HOME") + "/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py"

for line in fileinput.input(setup_file, inplace=True):
    print line.replace(setup_line, new_setup_line),

for line in fileinput.input(setup_file, inplace=True):
    print line.replace("#c.NotebookApp.password_required = False", "c.NotebookApp.password_required = True"),
```

Comment: This is awesome. Had to modify a bit for python3

Comment: Here is my python-3 compatible version https://gist.github.com/asherp/71a922a7eea9f5b2aba0faa8362f5fbc

Answer (score 3):

To setup a password from bash using a echo, you can do the following

```sh
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.password="$(echo PUT_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE | python -c 'from notebook.auth import passwd;print(passwd(input()))')"
```

Please notice that sending password over an echo is highly insecure.

Answer (score 3):

This has changed recently. `from notebook.auth.passwd` and `from IPython.lib.security.passwd` are not available anymore. Use:

```bash
PW_HASH=$(python -c \
    "from jupyter_server.auth import passwd; print(passwd('$YOUR_PASSWORD'))")
```

To get the hash. And then:

```bash
echo "c.ServerApp.password=u'$PW_HASH'" >>$JUPYTER_CONFIG;
```

To write the hash to the `jupyter_server_config.py`. It is *maybe* located at  `/root/.jupyter/jupyter_server_config.py`. Also, don't forget to generate it:

```bash
jupyter lab --generate-config;
```